Executing jupyter notebook Cell without moving to the next cell in VSCode
Im using jupyter notebook with VSCode as the editor.
Everytime I execute a cell the cursor gets shifted to a couple of cells down from thw executing cell and I will have to scroll up a bit to get to the output cell. Is there a way to have the active cursor stay in place even after i execute the cell?
